# Table index out of bounds allthough the table is bigger than the index

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a simple matching game and I want to output a leaderboard, but i get an exception array index out of bounds. In the debug though it says that the table's size is 3 and that both i and j are 0 and 1, which is weird to me becouse that is not out of bounds since the array size is 3. This is my code for sorting the array of objects from biggest to smallest by the highscore, thanks for the help.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<tabUporabnikov.Length-1; i++)
        {

            for(int j = (i+1); j<tabUporabnikov.Length; j++)
            {
                if (tabUporabnikov[i].highscore < tabUporabnikov[j].highscore)
                {
                    Uporabnik[] zacasna = new Uporabnik[1];
                    zacasna[1] = tabUporabnikov[j];
                    tabUporabnikov[j] = tabUporabnikov[i];
                    tabUporabnikov[i] = zacasna[1];
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `zacasna` has space for 0 or 1 items.

Comment: You're trying to set `zacasna[1]` even though you've just created it with one element. It's not clear why you're creating an array there at all though. Why not just a local variable `Uporabnik tmp = tabUporabnikov[j];`? (Then set `tabUporabnikov[i] = tmp;` as the last line in the block).

Comment: it should be `zacasna[0]`. better you declare a variable instead of array

Comment: Also note that there are built-in sorting methods in .NET - unless your aim is to learn about how to implement a sort, I'd suggest using either `Array.Sort` or LINQ.

Comment: Yes I tried to use the System.Linq but got issues with embeding it in the environment. I don't know yet how to do it becouse when I tried it crashed all my files and I had to start over from my backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `zacasna[0]`. Aray can have only one value in this case and array starts with index 0. so it should be `zacasna[0]`.  better you declare a variable instead of array because you need to store only value. declare it as `Uporabnik zacasna`

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue. At first I didn't even know why it solved it but now I see as to why.